# помогите разобраться в миграциях yii2

Tags: база-данных, yii2, миграция, зависимости, postgresql9.6

итак у меня есть:

1. меню
2. разделы
3. блюда

блюда находятся в определенном разделе, а разделы находятся в определенном меню

в качестве ДБ я использую postgresql 9.6

я создал первую миграцию для меню:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
    }

    $this->createTable('{{%menu_list}}', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'title_ru' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'title_en' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'url' => $this->string(),
        'img_url' => $this->string(),
        'weight' => $this->integer(),

        'status' => $this->smallInteger()->notNull()->defaultValue(1),
        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
    ], $tableOptions);

    $this->createIndex('FK_menu', '{{%menu_list}}', 'id');
}

public function safeDown()
{
    $this->dropTable('{{%menu_list}}');
}
```

и вторую миграцию для разделов и блюд:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $tableOptions = null;
    if ($this->db->driverName === 'mysql') {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
        $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
    }

    $this->createTable('{{%category}}', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'title_ru' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'title_en' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'url' => $this->string(),
        'img_url' => $this->string(),
        'weight' => $this->integer(),
        'menu_id' => $this->integer()->notNull(),

        'status' => $this->smallInteger()->notNull()->defaultValue(1),
        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->timestamp(),
    ], $tableOptions);

    $this->createTable('{{%dish}}', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'title_ru' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'title_en' => $this->string()->notNull(),
        'desc_ru' => $this->string(),
        'desc_en' => $this->string(),
        'url' => $this->string(),
        'img_url' => $this->string(),
        'weight' => $this->integer(),
        'category_id' => $this->integer()->notNull(),

        'status' => $this->smallInteger()->notNull()->defaultValue(1),
        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        ], $tableOptions);

    $this->createIndex('FK_dish_category', '{{%dish}}', 'category_id');
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'FK_dish_category', '{{%dish}}', 'category_id', '{{%category}}', 'id', 'SET NULL', 'CASCADE'
    );

    $this->createIndex('FK_category_menu', '{{%category}}', 'menu_id');
    $this->addForeignKey(
        'FK_category_menu', '{{%category}}', 'menu_id', '{{%menu_list}}', 'id', 'SET NULL', 'CASCADE'
    );
}

public function safeDown()
{
    $this->dropTable('{{%dish}}');
    $this->dropTable('{{%category}}');
}
```

все было бы ничего, да вот только при попытке сгенерить код через CRUD самого yii2 для модели которую я создал для таблицы category, у меня без всяких ошибок просто редиректит с ошибкой

> Error (#1) An internal server error occurred.

(http://joxi.ru/p27oVyRfodp0y2)

сдается мне что у меня не правильно написана миграция и в результате создалась не правильная модель с неправильными зависимостями и не генерируется код с помощью CRUD именно для модели category(для остальных моделей все сгенерилось нормально), помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Включите отображение ошибок на странице. Для этого в `/web/index.php`  вместо первых строк укажите это `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');` После этого, на странице, вместо `An internal server error occurred` будет описана суть ошибки. Там и будем разбираться дальше в чём проблема.

Comment: спасибо, включил отображение ошибок, оказывается:
таблица у меня называлась menu_list а сам контроллер - Menu,
а в модели генератор прописывал 'targetClass' => MenuList::className()
увидел ошибку, сразу поправил, спасибо за помощь!